# Get Query Parameter from URL into MVC View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I have an a `href` link to a page which adds a parameter to the link for example:
[tsw/register-your-interest?Course=979](http://tsw/register-your-interest?Course=979)

What I am trying to do is to extract the value in `Course` i.e 979 and display it in the `view`. When attempting with the below code, I only return with 0 rather than the course value expected. ideally I'd like to avoid using `routes`.

Here is the view:

```
<div class="contact" data-component="components/checkout">

            @using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm<CourseEnquiryPageSurfaceController>("PostCourseEnquiryForm", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "checkout__form" }))
            {
                //@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
                @Model.Course;
            }
```

And my controller:

```
 public ActionResult CourseEnquiry(string Course)
    {
        var model = Mapper.Map<CourseEnquiryVM>(CurrentContent);

        model.Course = Request.QueryString["Course"];
        return model
     }
```

This is the View Model:

```
public class CourseEnquiryVM : PageContentVM
{

    public List<OfficeLocation> OfficeLocations { get; set; }
    public string Test { get; set; }
    public string Course { get; set; }
    public List<Source> SourceTypes { get; set; }
}
```

SOLUTION:
After some research and comments I've adjusted the code to the below which now retrieves the value as expected

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Course, new { Value = @HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["Course"]});
```

Thanks all

Comment: What is the value of parameter (string Course) right when you break into the controller?

Comment: I would think the formal parameter Course has the value you are looking for in the request.

Comment: @BenKrueger - Not sure what answer is correct - What I'm expecting is to see 979 in string Course but not sure its working (see the first url)

Comment: @RossBush It does but I am unable to pull this into the view for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the form code you provided you need to use `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Course)` instead of just `@Model.Course`. `@Model.Course` just displays the value as text instead of building a input element that will be sent back to your controller.

If your problem is with a link prior to the view you referenced above, here's what I'd expect to work:

View with link:

```
@model CourseEnquiryVM

@Html.ActionLink("MyLink","CourseEnquiry","CourseController", new {course = @Model.Course}, null)
```

CourseController:

```
public ActionResult CourseEnquiry(string course)
{
    // course should have a value at this point
}
```

Comment: Correct, but in that case I guess OP also need to get a model object in his controller action method. Currently it's getting string.

Comment: adding this still returns 0 when I submit the form

Comment: @derloopkat IIRC the default model binder handles top level properties the same as action parameters. Both would expect to be given an `id` of `Course` in this case.

Comment: @PaulAlmond I think I misunderstood, you have another view that has the Course appended to the url, correct? Unless you have custom routing it doesn't look like your Action lines up with your form or your example URL. I also don't know how Umbraco affects routing/binding.

Comment: @Kyle you are somewhat right - My workflow is a page with multiple courses - The user presses a button it captures and passes the course ID to use in a form to enquire about places. I think based on peoples comments I'm going to have to using routing

Comment: @PaulAlmond, if that solved the problem please mark as answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your view, you are only displaying the value of `Course`.. which isn't able to be submitted.  You need to incorporate the value of course with a form input element (textbox, checkbox, textarea, hidden, etc.).

I would highly suggest using `EditorFor` or `Textboxfor`, but because your controller action is expecting just a `string` parameter you could just use `Editor` or `TextBox`.

```
@using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm<CourseEnquiryPageSurfaceController>("PostCourseEnquiryForm", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "checkout__form" }))
{
    //@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
    @Html.TextBox(Model.Course, null, new { @class = "form-control"});

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Then you should just be able to do this in your controller:

```
 public ActionResult CourseEnquiry(string course) // parameter variables are camel-case
{
    var model = Mapper.Map<CourseEnquiryVM>(CurrentContent);

    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(course))
        model.Course = course;

    return model;
 }
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Am i correct in assuming this will allow me to update the value using the form but not retrieve it from the URL?

Comment: Yes, I don't see why you need to retrieve it from the URL in the first place when you could just send it via form to the controller

Comment: You're correct - the issue is its always sending with a value of 0 and not the url value

Comment: Can you try just doing a normal `@Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post,....)` instead of `Html.BeginUmbracoForm<CourseEnquiryPageSurfaceController>`?